# How to add a custom meta data using custom resolvers as PageTitleResolver , PageDescriptionResolver etc

Tags: spartacus-storefront

i created a page extending "ContentPageMetaResolver" that implements PageRobotsResolver

```
export class MyContentPageMetaResolver extends ContentPageMetaResolver implements
PageRobotsResolver {

pageType = PageType.CONTENT_PAGE;
pageTemplate = 'StaticContentPageTemplate';

resolveRobots(): Observable<PageRobotsMeta[]> {
  return of(new Array(PageRobotsMeta.NOFOLLOW, PageRobotsMeta.NOINDEX));
}
}
```

As a result this is adding the the following entry to the head element of the page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOFOLLOW, NOINDEX">
```

Now i need to do the same thing for keywords. Any idea how to create a custom resolver implementation ?

The PageRobotsResolver interface is provided out of the box in page.resolvers.d.ts file:

```
/**
* Resolves the robot information for the page. This is used by
* search engines to understand whether the page and subsequential links
* should be indexed.
*
*/

export interface PageRobotsResolver {
/**
 * Resolves the robots for the page.
 *
 * @deprecated since version 1.3
 * Use `resolveRobots()` instead.
 */
resolveRobots(...args: any[]): Observable<PageRobotsMeta[]>;
/**
 * Resolves the robots for the page.
 */
resolveRobots(): Observable<PageRobotsMeta[]>;
```

}

And added the following to my providers list of my module :

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
    { provide: ContentPageMetaResolver, useExisting: MyContentPageMetaResolver }
]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageMetaResolver` are used by the `PageMetaService` to generate page meta data. Specific meta data can be added in a *specific* resolver (i.e. in your `MyContentPageMetaResolver`), or you could extend the `PageMetaResolver` to gather additional metadata for all resolvers.

By default, Spartacus iterates (from feature flag `1.3`) over various resolvers, and - if the resolver is implemented – adds the resolved data to the page meta model. This is done in the `PageMetaService`, and you *could* (but should not ;), see below) extend the list of `resolverMethods` in that service so that your custom method is called.

An alternative (but less flexible) approach would be to provide a custom `SeoMetaService`, and override the `meta` setter. Also, the `SeoMetaService` is limited to page meta data, while the `PageMetaService` can contribute to other areas of the application, such as structural data.

Whether the use of keywords in 2020 is still a good idea, I'd recommend to read up on this, as crawlers seem to stop worrying for this a long time ago. This is the reason why we haven't added a default resolver in Spartacus, but if you come up with good arguments to do so, I'm eager to learn!

Comment: Thanks @tobi-or-not-tobi for your answer. You first suggestion seems to be the simplest way. How can i achieve that in my class MyContentPageMetaResolver ?

Comment: About the other ways to do the job can you please provide me more details on how i can implement that ?

Comment: About the keywords meta it s because we need to provide the same meta data that are actually provided in the content pages in the current hybris implementation. As  a kind of PoC, we are starting by content pages and the result is expected to be the same as  what already exists online provided by the old and monolithique version in the store front

Comment: Can you also please tell me why we should not  extend the list of resolverMethods in  PageMetaService ? And even if i have to use this way how can i implement this solution ? 

```export class MyPageMetaService extends PageMetaService{
  constructor(...){
     super(...)
     this.resolverMethods.keywords = 'resolveKeywords';
  } 
}```

then implement "resolveKeywords" methods in my resolver  (MyContentPageMetaResolver) ? but how to have MyPageMetaService used instead of the parent ?

Comment: i extended PageMetaService as follow : 
```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SeoModule } from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: SeoModule,
  })
export class myPageMetaService extends PageMetaService {

    resolverMethods: {
        title: string;
        heading: string;
        description: string;
        breadcrumbs: string;
        image: string;
        robots: string;
        keywords: string;
    };
   constructor(...) {
       super(...);
       this.resolverMethods.keywords = 'resolveKeywords';
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: do we need also to extend SeoMetaService and use MyPageMetaService instead of  PageMetaService ?